# UIView nested in UIViewController top buttons

Tags: xcode, uiview, uikit, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I want to create some "template" view using Interface Builder, in my storyboard, I dragged and dropped a UIView on top of a UIViewController like that :
[image: Mode Presentation View]

I modified it (in IB) and than made a custom subclass of UIView (and "linked" it by specifying that the view class is my custom class.

The problem is when I try to use it somewhere else in my code, such as :

```
let a = MyCustomView()
a.myLabel.text = "This is a test"
```

myLabel outlet is nil, even if I linked it from IB by ctrl+dragging, what should I do ?

Is it a good practice to create reusable views this way ? Or is it just not possible at all to do that ?

Thank you.